# com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, parse-platform

1. This is showing an error as "com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String".

2.I don't know where is the mistake...

3. Please help me on this....
   I am using the parse server to add some data into database of parse..
   By using the parseObject i tried to add data into data base but it throws some exceptions
    **"com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be 
   cast to java.lang.String"**

The code starts from here..................................

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import org.json.JSONObject;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

// Enable Local Datastore.
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

// Add your initialization code here
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .applicationId("93de5c14d8cc6ac5655e66474efe77f556c4ea8a")
        .clientKey("6b92758701c6f1b71cd1ae5ebf5200aa1db2e3ee")
        .server("http://18.222.204.81:80/parse/")
        .build()
);


ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ExampleObject");
object.put("myNumber","143");
object.put("myString","143");


object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseException ex) {
    if (ex == null) {
      Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
    } else {
      Log.i("Parse Result", "Failed" + ex.toString());
    }
  }
});
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

}
    }

```
enter code here
03-26 06:57:27.464 4926-4926/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10069: Read-only 
file system
03-26 06:57:27.465 4926-4926/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing 
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
03-26 06:57:27.466 4926-4926/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-26 06:57:27.773 4926-4926/com.parse.starter I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization 
unsuccessful
03-26 06:57:27.967 4926-4941/com.parse.starter I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC 
freed 2322(116KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 1039KB/1135KB, paused 4.954ms total 
127.439ms
03-26 06:57:28.082 4926-4941/com.parse.starter I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC 
freed 1462(134KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 44% free, 1298KB/2MB, paused 10.061ms total 
105.500ms
03-26 06:57:28.200 4926-4926/com.parse.starter W/art: Before Android 4.1, method 
android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 
android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter
(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorF 
ilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly 
overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-26 06:57:28.330 4926-4958/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
03-26 06:57:28.413 4926-4926/com.parse.starter D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-26 06:57:28.431 4926-4926/com.parse.starter I/Parse Result: Failedcom.parse.ParseException: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
03-26 06:57:28.515 4926-4958/com.parse.starter D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-26 06:57:28.521 4926-4958/com.parse.starter D/libEGL: loaded 
/system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-26 06:57:28.554 4926-4958/com.parse.starter D/libEGL: loaded 
/system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-26 06:57:28.606 4926-4958/com.parse.starter I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-26 06:57:28.662 4926-4958/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-26 06:57:28.696 4926-4958/com.parse.starter W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-26 06:57:28.696 4926-4958/com.parse.starter W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on 
surface 0xefd07f40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Do you know which line is throwing the error?

Comment: The line where i made the ParseObject.  I have searched for this problem and all i know is that to use the HashMap but i don't know how to use it

Comment: Can you please remove the 5 last lines just in case and try again?

Comment: hey Bro , Thanks for your  suggestion i just found the mistake in the code.. There was a problem with my connection with parse. I made it right and the code works properly..